# Applying decorator to specific type e.g. text or select

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I'm know how to add custom decorators and use view helpers to set decorators for named elements.

Is their a method or an attribute that would allow me to set a default decorator for all textareas or for all text inputs or all selects?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

yes you can override default zend decorator for your html object like textarea or text box

here is good example to create our own decomrator [Link](http://blog.philipbrown.id.au/2009/10/overriding-zend-form-element-default-decorators-for-good/)

Comment: That doesnt really answer the question. 
I am already comfertable using custom decorators and custom libraries.

What I am asking isn't how to set custome decorator classes but how to specifically add a decorator to all classes base on the type attrubute.

e.g. what be the syntax for a custom decorator for all for FormElements of type textarea